# Had to reinstall Win10, now no USB devices work

Tags: windows-10, usb, keyboard

I recently did a clean install of windows 10 Pro due to an MBR vs GPT issue (and my computer not recognizing my system disk after a soft reboot). Since the reinstall, no USB devices connected to the onboard Intel USB controller work. They get power; they work in the BIOS (I can use a USB keyboard in the BIOS), but once I get to Windows, it's like they don't exist.

My motherboard (Asus Rampage Extreme IV) has 2 USB controllers, the onboard Intel and an ASMedia controller. All of the ASMedia ports work, but the Intel ones refuse. Near as I can tell from device manager, etc, everything is on the latest driver. I have 2 unknown USB devices - but I know that's my Saitek X55 Rhino (I've not set it up yet). My computer won't even recognize my keyboard (I'm typing this on an aux keyboard plugged into one of the front USBs). My keyboard is nothing special - a MS Intelitype Ergonomic 4000 that has worked for years.

I don't really know if anything on the Intel USB hub is functioning correctly, but I know they're getting power - LEDs, etc are lighting.

I've already reinstalled/restored windows about 5 times tonight and I'm running out of hair to pull out. Any advice would be appreciated.

NOTE: the keyboard is wired, not wireless.

Comment: Is the chipset driver installed? You can get one from [Asus Global website](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/RAMPAGE_IV_EXTREME/HelpDesk_Download/)

Comment: Yeah, the chipset drivers were installed. I have it resolved now - I'm not quite sure exactly what fixed it. I "uninstalled" the 2 unrecognized devices I had - turned out to the USB 2.0 hubs. After I did that, I had to reboot to install the drivers. Same reboot also took me from build 14376 to 14379. So, not sure exactly what fixed it. It's just weird. I've had this PC for about 4 years now, reinstalled windows numerous times and I've never had it not have drivers for the USB controllers.